# References about the works of compact complex surface by Kodaira?

Tags: complex-geometry

I have found the original papers about these, but they are not easy to read(different notations and bad composition）Are there some books or notes contains this topic?

Comment: Have you read _Compact Complex Surfaces_ by Barth, Hulek, Peters and Van de Ven? I didn't read Kodaira's paper in details, but I suppose the result is covered in this book.

Comment: @AGlearner Thank you for your recommendation! I heard about this book before and I haven’t read it. For now according to the table of contents, it might cover what I need.